# how do you make the product attributes on view pages into drop downs

Tags: magento2

i am using magento 2.2. i want to make my configurable product attributes, like Product size, into dropdowns.

how do i do that. i noticed its possible from this picture on another forum[image]

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the question...

Yes, it's possible.

To do that, please visit on following screenshots:-

1- [image]
But Screenshot 1 is not enough due to the bug in Magento2, so please visit next screenshots to complete it.

2- In the table eav_attribute_option_swatch

[image]

3- [image]

[Reference](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9307)

I've also tested by doing above steps & I achieve the result & hope you too.